# Using rename to safely overwrite a shared file in Linux

Tags: c, linux, rename, atomic, file-locking

Here is the setup: I have a shared file (lets call it status.csv) that is read by many processes (lets call them consumers) in a read-only fashion. I have one producer that periodically updates status.csv by creating a temp file, writing data to it and using the C function discussed here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Renaming-Files.html

to rename the temp file (effectively overwrite) to status.csv so that the consumers can process the new data. It want to try and guarantee (as much as possible in the Linux world) that the consumers won't get a malformed/corrupted/half-old/half-new status.csv file (I want them to get either all of the old data or all of the new). I can't seem to guarantee this by reading the description of rename: it seems to guarantee that the rename action itself is atomic but I want to know if a consumer already has the status.csv file open, he will continue to read the same file as it was when it was opened, even if the file is renamed/overwritten by the producer in the middle of this reading operation.

I attempted to prototype this thinking that the consumers will get some type of error or a half old/half new file but it seems to always be in the state it was when it was open by the consumer even if renamed/overwritten multiple times.

BTW, these processes are running on the same machine (RHEL 6).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux and similar systems, if a process has a file open and the file is deleted, the file itself remains undeleted until all processes close it. All that happens immediately is that the directory entry is deleted so that it cannot be opened again.

The same thing happens if rename is used to replace an open file. The old file descriptor still keeps the old file open. However, new opens will see the new file.

Therefore, for your consumers to see the new file, they must close and reopen the file.

Note: your consumers can discover if the file has been replaced by using the `stat`(2) call. If either the `st_dev` or `st_ino` entries (or both) have changed, then the file has been replaced and must be closed and reopened. This is how `tail -F` works.

Comment: I would note that generally this is true, but it is not universal. It depends on the underlying file system, and there are some that don't actually work that way (usually because they weren't originally Linux/Unix file systems, but still...)...